# TopTabNavigator backgroundColor

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change backgroundColor in TopTabNavigator without luck and hope some one can guide me in the right directions.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import FoldersList from '../screens/FoldersList';

const Routes = {
  Home: {
    screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={0} />,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
        tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      }
    }
  },
  NewTab: {
    screen: (props) => <FoldersList {...props} tabIndex={1} createFolderTitle='Create new tab folder' />,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'New'
    }
  }
};

const routeConfig = {
  swipeEnabled: false
};

export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  ...Routes
}, routeConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `routeConfig` :

```js
const routeConfig = {
  swipeEnabled: false,
  tabBarOptions: {
    ...,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#eceff1',
      // other style
    },
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the docs , you can add background color to tabs by adding the below code in your `routeConfig`

```
const routeConfig = {
  swipeEnabled: false,

 tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue', // this is to be added and color you want
  },
 }
};
```

Hope it helps. feel free for any doubts.

Comment: Thank you for the help.